# Pasar nombre de tabla como parametro a una funcion en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy intentando pasar el nombre de una tabla como parametro de una funcion , pero por algun motivo me devuelve todo el rato error de sintaxis.

¿Ideas?

```
include '../ruta_de_la_conexion.php';
function ObtenerTablas($Tabla_a_devolver){
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("Select * from :tabla_a_pasar");
         $stmt->bindParam(':tabla_a_pasar', $Tabla_a_devolver);
        $stmt->execute();
        while ($fila = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo $fila;
        }       
    }   
    ObtenerTablas("tabla_a_imprimir");
```

---

Pd: Uso PDO para BBDD , y la conexion esta obviamente bien.

Edit: os adjunto el error que obtengo con los diferentes codigos.

---

Con tu codigo @FranIslas

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\Practica_Cursos_Formacion\Listar_cursos\Listar_cursos.php:15 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Practica_Cursos_Formacion\Listar_cursos\Listar_cursos.php(15): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Practica_Cursos_Formacion\Listar_cursos\Listar_cursos.php(26): ObtenerArrays('solicitudes') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Practica_Cursos_Formacion\Listar_cursos\Listar_cursos.php on line 15
```

Con el que pongo aqui sin modificar nada:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''solicitudes'' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Practica_Cursos_Formacion\Listar_cursos\Listar_cursos.php:13 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Practica_Cursos_Formacion\Listar_cursos\Listar_cursos.php(13): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Practica_Cursos_Formacion\Listar_cursos\Listar_cursos.php(24): ObtenerArrays('solicitudes') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Practica_Cursos_Formacion\Listar_cursos\Listar_cursos.php on line 13
```

Con el codigo de @Byro:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function real_escape_string() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Practica_Cursos_Formacion\Listar_cursos\Listar_cursos.php:12 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Practica_Cursos_Formacion\Listar_cursos\Listar_cursos.php(26): ObtenerArrays('solicitudes') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Practica_Cursos_Formacion\Listar_cursos\Listar_cursos.php on line 12
```

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: prueba cambiar `$stmt = $conn->prepare("Select * from :tabla_a_pasar"); $stmt->bindParam(':tabla_a_pasar', $Tabla_a_devolver);` por  `$stmt = $conn->prepare("Select * from ?"); $stmt->bindParam('s',$Tabla_a_devolver);`

Comment: @FranIslas me sale mas de lo mismo :(

Comment: Puedes agregar el error a la pregunta? Generalmente te indica en que parte está mal la sintaxis.

Comment: @FranIslas hay lo tienes y ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A pesar de que el caso parece resuelto, creo conveniente explicar a qué se debió el error y de paso indicar algunos *errores de implementación* que persisten en el código de la respuesta aceptada.

En el código inicial se muestra que intentas usar consultas preparadas con un nombre de tabla, lo cual está prohibido, porque las consultas preparadas tienen una finalidad muy distinta. De hecho, no puedes usar consultas preparadas para pasar nombres de tablas o columnas, sino solamente valores relativos a las columnas que participan en la instrucción SQL.

Esto no queda claramente explicado en el Manual de PHP, pero sí hay [una nota de contribución que lo explica y que me permito colocar aquí traducida](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php#111977) para futuros usuarios:

> Para aquellos que se preguntan por qué agregar comillas a un marcador
>   de posición es incorrecto, y por qué no puede usar los marcadores de
>   posición para los nombres de tablas o columnas:
>
> Hay una idea errónea común acerca de cómo funcionan los marcadores de
>   posición en las declaraciones preparadas: no se sustituyen simplemente
>   como cadenas (escapadas), y se ejecuta el SQL resultante. En su lugar,
>   un DBMS al que se le pidió que "prepare" una declaración presenta un
>   plan de consulta completo sobre cómo ejecutaría esa consulta,
>   incluidas las tablas e índices que usaría, que serán los mismos
>   independientemente de cómo complete los marcadores de posición.
>
> El plan para `SELECT name FROM my_table WHERE id =:value` será el
>   mismo que sustituya por `:value`, pero el similar <s>`SELECT name FROM
>   :table WHERE id =:value`</s> no se puede planificar, porque el DBMS no
>   tiene idea de qué tabla vas a seleccionar.
>
> Incluso cuando se usan "preparaciones emuladas", PDO no puede permitir
>   usar marcadores de posición en cualquier lugar, ya que tendría que
>   resolver lo que querría decir: `Select :foo From some_table` ¿`:foo`
>   será una referencia de columna, o una cadena literal?
>
> Cuando tu consulta utiliza una referencia de columna dinámica, debe
>   incluir explícitamente en la lista blanca las columnas que sabe que
>   existen en la tabla, por ejemplo utilizando una instrucción `switch`
>   con una excepción lanzada en la cláusula `default`

---

Entendido esto, podemos pasar ahora a señalar que hay *errores de implementación*  en tu código, en el sentido de que:

- No necesitas realmente usar `filter_var` ¿Para qué habría que filtrar el nombre de la tabla aquí? A lo sumo, si quieres establecer un control de seguridad puedes tener una lista blanca de tablas en tu programa y comparar el nombre de la tabla en esa lista blanca.
- No necesitas en este caso usar consultas preparadas. No hay en esta consulta ningún riesgo de inyección.
- El estilo `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` crea un array asociativo en cada fila, por lo tanto para imprimir debes poner el nombre de cada columna que quieras mostrar, algo así: `echo $fila["unaColumna"]." ".$fila["otraColumna"]`

Por tanto, el código puede escribirse simplemente así:

```
include '../ruta_de_la_conexion.php';
function ObtenerTablas($Tabla_a_devolver){
        $stmt = $conn->query("Select * from $Tabla_a_devolver");
        while ($fila = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo $fila["unaColumna"].PHP_EOL;
        }       
    }   

ObtenerTablas("tabla_a_imprimir");
```

Es muy importante comprender en qué casos hay que usar `query` y en qué casos hay que usar `prepare`. Realmente en este caso **no hay nada que preparar** realmente, simplemente pasar el nombre de la tabla a la instrucción y ejecutar.

> #### EDICIÓN POSTERIOR
>
> Es cierto que siempre podría existir un riesgo de inyección, un
>   usuario mal intencionado podría intentar escribir el nombre de la
>   tabla así:
>
> ```
> persona; DELETE FROM persona;  -- No probar esto, es peligroso
> ```
>
> Este intento de inyección podría colar, si el objeto PDO tuviese
>   activas las preparaciones emuladas.
>
> Lo correcto, en el caso de querer pasar nombres de tablas como
>   parámetro, es manejar una lista blanca de tablas permitidas y pasar
>   por ese filtro cualquier parámetro que se le pase a `ObtenerTablas` o
>   a cualquier otra función que reciba una tabla en parámetro.
>
> En ese sentido puedes tener por ejemplo una `clase` dedicada a ello, o
>   poner el método de validación dentro de una clase utilitaria.
>
> Dicho método sería más o menos así:
>
> ```
> public function isValidTable($tableName){
>     $listTables=array('persona','ciudad','pais');
>     return in_array($tableName, $listTables);
> }
> ```
>
> Aquí sólo se admitirían consultas a las tablas `persona`, `ciudad` y `pais`.
>
> Y para usarlo:
>
> ```
> $tabla="tabla_a_imprimir";
> if ( isValidTable($tabla) ){
>     ObtenerTablas($tabla);
> }else{
>     echo "Error, tabla no válida";  //Se puede escribir en un log 
>                                     //para detectar intentos de hackeo 
>                                     //o enviar un email al administrador del sitio
> }
> ```

Comment: Excelente tu explicación, me queda una duda. Si por ejemplo yo hago la siguiente consulta `$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM $mi_tabla WHERE 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?");` con las preparaciones emuladas desactivadas, ya no hay riesgo de inyección ?

Comment: @LeonardoHenao es poco probable que haya riesgo de inyección. Es *casi* seguro que el manejador bloqueará cualquier consulta maliciosa. **Pero** tu consulta es manipulable  y por tanto no es correcta. Por ejemplo,  `$mi_tabla` puede ser sustituido por algo como `unaTablaReal; DELETE FROM unaTablaReal -- ` La inyección no pasará del intento, quizás, pero tú estás escribiendo una consulta que permite al menos que se intente. Una de las recomendaciones más eficaces contra inyección es precisamente crear una lista blanca de tablas, de modo que no se puede ejecutar ...

Comment: ... ninguna consulta fuera de las tablas incluidas en dicha lista. Si pasas el nombre de la tabla como una variable (manipulable por tanto), te colocas en el extremo contrario y niegas esa norma de seguridad. Es cierto también que los sistemas son más seguros. Por ejemplo, yo he intentado probar inyecciones parecidas a la mencionada con tablas de prueba por supuesto y he visto que las mismas han sido bloqueadas a nivel de `.htaccess` No estoy documentado al respecto, pero parece que también a ese nivel se detectan riesgos de inyección y son bloqueados sin siquiera pasar a PHP...

Comment: ... pero eso no significa que haya que bajar la guardia. Los usuarios maliciosos se modernizan también y crean nuevos riesgos de inyección. No puedes por tanto dejar ninguna puerta abierta en forma de `$mi_tabla`. Además, no tiene ningún sentido pasar el nombre de una tabla en una variable. Una tabla es una entidad del sistema y debes tratarla como tal. Si crees que ahorras trabajo o que estás escribiendo código reutilizable de ese modo, estás en un error. El código reutilizable se crea escribiendo un modelo de datos adecuado. En ese modelo, una tabla será una clase.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaracion, queria "Ahorrar" trabajo ya que tengo una app que maneja mas de 16 tablas en diferentes secciones y queria hacer una funcion en la cual simplemente pasara la tabla como variable y devolviera el contenido de ella. Lo que hice preferiblemente y por seguridad fue hacer un switch pasando un identificador de tabla y que regrese la consulta ya con el nombre de la tabla.

Comment: Entiendo @LeonardoHenao. Pero como ya dije, eso no es ahorrar trabajo. Cuando realmente ahorras trabajo es cuando concibes un buen modelo de datos. Supongamos que tienes varias tablas: `persona, ciudad, profesion`, creas igualmente tres clases `Persona, Ciudad, Profesion`, las alimentas con la información que obtienes de la  BD y usas los métodos de cada clase para obtener la información que requieras. Eso sí que es ahorrar trabajo, porque podrás usar la misma clase sin importar en qué contexto se requieran los datos. Esa es una de las maravillas de la POO.

Comment: @LeonardoHenao dado que en un comentario es difícil explicar lo que quiero decir, te dejo [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/233094/29967) y también [una auto-respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/233095/29967) a la misma que puede ser aclaratoria. Podrás ver lo fácil que es mapear un resultado PDO a una clase la cual estará dotada de los métodos que se requieran en tu contexto para darte la información. Así, cuando necesites datos de ese ente **en cualquier parte** sólo tendrás que invocar la clase que hace la consulta y te devuelve el objeto `Actor` (en este caso).

Answer (score 2):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
include '../ruta_de_la_conexion.php';
function ObtenerTablas($Tabla_a_devolver){
        $tabla = filter_var($Tabla_a_devolver, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("Select * from {$tabla}");
        $stmt->execute();
        while ($fila = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo $fila;
        }       
    }   
    ObtenerTablas("tabla_a_imprimir");
```

Comment: @Byro me temo que tampoco , edito la pregunta poniendo el error que obtengo con tu codigo .

Comment: ya hice la correccion pertinente pero esta vez con php!