# Pasar nombre de la tabla en el execute de la consulta (PDO)

Tags: php, php5

Explico rápidamente el por que deseo hacer el proceso así.

Tengo al rededor de 26 tablas con contenido diferente que se consulta desde una app (android) por medio de un web service.

Quiero hacer la consulta enviando un identificador para alguna tabla y en el archivo php por medio de un switch creo la variable `$table` la cual contiene el nombre de la tabla real (no el identificador).

El problema surge cuando paso la variable `$table` en el **execute** de la consulta, el error aparentemente es que la variable no esta definida `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on bool in...` ya que al colocar el nombre de la tabla directamente si funciona.

**Lo que estoy haciendo, pero quiero mejorar para no tener que hacer 26 casos**

```
 $rq= "";
 $table = $_REQUEST['t'];

 switch($table){
   case 'animals':
        $rq = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `wallp_animals` WHERE 1 ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?");
   break;
 }   

 $rq->execute(array($limit, $offset));
```

**Lo que quiero hacer pero no me funciona**

```
 $table = $_REQUEST['t'];
 $rq = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM ? WHERE 1 ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?"); 
 $rq->execute(array($table, $limit, $offset));
```

**Ya probé hacer la consulta así**

```
 $rq = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `?` WHERE 1 ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?"); 

 $rq = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM '?' WHERE 1 ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?");
```

**Lo que no quiero hacer, obviamente por seguridad**

```
 $table = $_REQUEST['t'];
 $rq = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE 1 ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?"); 
 $rq->execute(array($limit, $offset));
```

Muchas gracias por sus repuestas, espero haberme explicado lo mejor posible.

Comment: Pregunta relacionada con esta -> [Pasar nombre de tabla como parametro a una funcion en PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/228146/pasar-nombre-de-tabla-como-parametro-a-una-funcion-en-php)