# Error al usar GRANT MySql desde php

Tags: php, mysql

Si uso esta cadena funciona

```
$sentencia = $conexion->prepare("GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON pulpbianca.* TO ?@'%' IDENTIFIED BY ?;");
$sentencia->execute([$_POST["nombre"],$_POST["pasus"]]);
```

Pero deseo pasar la bd por parámetro usando esta

```
$sentencia = $conexion->prepare("GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON ?.* TO ?@'%' IDENTIFIED BY ?;");
$sentencia->execute([$_POST["db"],$_POST["nombre"],$_POST["pasus"]]);
```

Comment: Qué error te devuelve? Puedes probar usando errorInfo(): https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.errorinfo.php

Comment: Es imposible hacer eso. Las consultas preparadas no son para pasar en parámetro ni nombres de tabla, ni nombres de columna, ni mucho menos el nombre de la base de datos. Las consultas preparadas tienen el propósito de blindar contra Inyección SQL en los datos que manejan las consultas. Para otro tipo de operaciones dinámicas tendrías que crear tu propia lista blanca, verificar que el dato está en esa lista y entonces sustituirlo y mandar la consulta con el nombre explícito de la BD, tabla o columna.

Comment: Precisar que la principal razón de las sentencias preparadas es optimizar el rendimiento/procesamiento de sentencias similares que se ejecutarán varias veces; la prevención de inyecciones SQL es un beneficio secundario.

Answer (score 2):

Es imposible hacer lo que pretendes. Las consultas preparadas no son para pasar en parámetro ni nombres de tabla, ni nombres de columna, ni mucho menos el nombre de la base de datos (puedes consultar [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/228223/29967) para más detalles).

Lo más correcto y seguro para el caso que expones, sería crear una lista blanca de valores permitidos, pasar el nombre de base de datos, tabla o columna en parámatro tal cual y verificarlo contra esa lista blanca.

Ejemplo:

```
//Aquí $dbName equivaldría al valor de $_POST["db"]
function oneFunction ($dbName) {
    $allowed=array ("pulpbianca","bdPepito","bdJuanito");
    if ( in_array($dbName,$allowed) ) {
        $sql="GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON $dbName.* TO ?@'%' IDENTIFIED BY ?;";
        $sentencia = $conexcion->prepare($sql); 
        $sentencia->execute( array($_POST["nombre"],$_POST["pasus"]) );
    } else {
        //$dbName no está permitida, emitir un error o lo que quieras
    }
}
```

El caso es que en esta sentencia: `GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON $dbName.* TO` tienes que pasar el valor de la base de datos de forma literal, sí o sí. Pero aquí, verificando contra `$allowed` impides que se ejecute este código en bases de datos que no sean `pulpbianca`, `bdPepito` o `bdJuanito` (por poner un ejemplo :) ). Cualquier otro nombre distinto de esos no ejecutará el código. No hay otra forma de hacerlo, cuando se trata de nombres de base de datos, de tablas o de columnas.